# How to add a Default constraint while creating a table? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, constraint

I am trying to create a new table with columns followed by their constraint as shown below.

```
Create tblTest(
columns..
..
..
Gender int,
Constraint DF_tblTest_Gender Default 3 For Gender,
..
..
..
)
```

However, I am getting an error message near the default constraint as,

> 'Incorrect syntax near 'for''

Comment: You might want to have a look at the official Microsoft SQL Server documentation for the [`CREATE TABLE ...`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement. You have a very basic syntax error.

Answer (score 35):

You can name the constraint inline:

```
CREATE TABLE tblTest(
  --
  --
  Gender int CONSTRAINT DF_tblTest_Gender DEFAULT 3,
  --
) ;
```

As the [`CREATE TABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql) msdn page shows:

> `DEFAULT`
>
> ... To maintain compatibility with earlier versions of SQL Server, a constraint name can be assigned to a `DEFAULT`.

In the same page, we can find that the only options for `<table_constraint>` are `PRIMARY KEY`, `FOREIGN KEY` and `CHECK` constraints:

> ```
> < table_constraint > ::=  
>   [ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ]   
> {  
>    { PRIMARY KEY | UNIQUE }  
>        {   
>          NONCLUSTERED (column [ ASC | DESC ] [ ,... n ])  
>          | NONCLUSTERED HASH (column [ ,... n ] ) 
>                WITH ( BUCKET_COUNT = bucket_count )   
>        }   
>     | FOREIGN KEY   
>         ( column [ ,...n ] )   
>         REFERENCES referenced_table_name [ ( ref_column [ ,...n ] ) ]   
>     | CHECK ( logical_expression )   
> }
> ```

so if you want to add a default constraint (naming or not) the only ways are by doing it inline or with an `ALTER TABLE` statement.

Answer (score 12):

Your comments on the other two answers claim that you cannot name a default constraint when creating it "inline".  Both answers show that you can, in fact, provide a name for the constraint when creating it inline.  I'll add a third example, showing the results.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Test') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Test;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
(
    TestID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Test --here I'm naming the primary key constraint!
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , SomeData varchar(42) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT DF_Test_SomeData --this is the name of the default constraint!
        DEFAULT ('Carrie Fisher')
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Test DEFAULT VALUES;
```

This shows the name of the default constraint is `DF_Test_SomeData`:

```
SELECT TableName = t.name
    , ConstraintName = dc.name
FROM sys.default_constraints dc
    INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON dc.parent_object_id = t.object_id;
```

Results:

[image]

Looking at the object explorer in SSMS shows the name:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `default value` on the field definition.

```
Create tblTest(
columns..
..
..
Gender int CONSTRAINT constraint_name DEFAULT 3,
..
..
..
)
```

Or use ALTER TABLE:

```
ALTER TABLE tblTest
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name 
DEFAULT 3
FOR Gender
```